# Dynamic Brushes in XAML

Tags: wpf, drawing, paint, brush

I have a definition for a data template that looks as follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type HeatMap:BlockItem}">
        <Grid  Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}">
            <Border Name="BlockBorder" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Colour}" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

As can be seen, `BlockItem` has a property of type `Color` called `Colour` which is bound to the first color of the `LinearGradientBrush` which fills a border, making it look like a filled rectangle.

Now I don't always want Linear Gradient Brushes to style the fill of this rectangle. Some rectangles on my canvas may need to be filled with SolidBrushes, for example. I considered creating a `Brush` property on the `BlockItem` class instead of a `Color` property and binding the entire `Border.Background` to that, but there are 2 problems with this:

- I don't know how the XAML should look to specify a binding to the entire object `Background` property.
- In the code where I create `BlockItem`s, if  I instantiate a new Brush for every single BlockItem (bear in mind, there maybe be many drawn on a canvas at a time), will this not make it really inefficient and slow?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can bind the Background directly to a brush on your BlockItem:

```
<Border Name="BlockBorder" Background="{Binding MyBackgroundBrush}">
```

2) You could bind to a static resource, or create a static brush for your BlockItem.

```
Background="{StaticResource myStaticBrush}"
```